# Sticky sessions not sticky on coldfusion cluster

Tags: cluster, coldfusion, jrun

we're trying to deploy a legacy coldfusion site onto a new CF8 cluster.

The cluster consists of three cf instances running under JRUN4 on a single windows 2008 server.

I've got the cluster set to not replicate sessions, and sticky sessions turned on. each instance is set to use J2EE session variables.

The application tag for the site has:

```
sessionmanagement="Yes"
setclientcookies="Yes"
setdomaincookies="Yes"
```

when each instance starts... no errors are reported in the instance log and they join the cluster without any issues.

though the intances do have:

```
16/10 08:31:25 info
SessionReplicationService successfully
joined a JINI lookup service (assigned
JINI-ID .....)
```

and

```
16/10 08:31:25 info Clusterable
service SessionReplicationService
discovered a SessionReplicationService
peer on a JRun server named
"xxxx" on host xxxx
```

which is interesting since session replication is definately off, is the SessionReplicationService responsible for sticky sessions aswell?

thats enough background, the problem is that the sticky sessions appear to simply not work, each request is bounced to a different instance, and it seems as if the sessions are being lost on each instance anyways?

As soon as the cluster is down to a single instance, the web app works exactly as expected and the sessions seem fine.

has anybody got any ideas for me? i've been trawling the web and I cant seem to find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the settings in jrun-web.xml and jrun.xml reflects your CF admin or code settings.  In my experience they don't always sync properly.